# updating Sqlite table if string field starts with plus (+) sign?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I have a sqlite table for my android application. This table has a String field (phone). When I want to insert or update a phone number starts with + plus-sign (e.g "+905331234567") then it ignores the plus sign. It writes only 905331234567.
But when I modify the value with space (or any other except numeric) chars, 
(eg." +905331234567"), then no problem.

```
update friend set phone = "+905331234567"; //905331234567
update friend set phone = " +905331234567";// +905331234567
```

thanks for your reply.
kemal.

---

**Edit**

Create String:

```
private static final String CREATE_FRIEND =  // create table 
        "create table " + FriendBean.DB_TABLE_NAME + "(" + 
        FriendBean.KEY_ROWID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " +
        FriendBean.KEY_contactID + " String, " +
        FriendBean.KEY_name + " String, " +
        FriendBean.KEY_phone + " String, " +
        FriendBean.KEY_accessCode + " String, " +
        FriendBean.KEY_flag + " int " +
        ");";
```

Insert method:

```
public void insertFriend(FriendBean bean) {
    SQLiteStatement statement = database.compileStatement(FriendBean.getInsertSQL());    

    statement.bindString(1,bean.getContactID());
    statement.bindString(2,bean.getName());
    statement.bindString(3,bean.getPhone() +"");
    statement.bindString(4,bean.getAccessCode());
    statement.bindLong(5,bean.getFlag());

    long id= statement.executeInsert();
}
```

Class:

```
public class FriendBean{

    public static final String DB_TABLE_NAME = "friend";

    public static final String KEY_contactID = "contactID";
    public static final String KEY_name = "name";
    public static final String KEY_phone = "phone";
    public static final String KEY_accessCode = "accessCode";
    public static final String KEY_flag = "flag";
    ...
```

Solution: 
**String** Fieldtype replaced with **Text**.

references
http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html
and
comments.

Comment: http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Comment: Please post your code, since a SQLiteDatabase `TEXT` datatype does not absorb the "+". How are you storing, retrieving and displaying these rows?

Comment: you need to use text not string as your column types.

Comment: phone field type is String, may I create as TEXT ?

Comment: Yes, problem was solved. Thank you very much, Sam and superfell:)

Comment: @chrome - If you did solve the problem, could you post an answer that describes what you did so that future visitors can benefit? There's no harm in posting an answer to your own question.

Comment: @chrome - Rather than editing a solution into the question, could you take what you added and create an actual answer and accept that so that the question isn't being listed as unsolved?

Comment: @chrome I already have phone number column as TEXT but still having the problem. Can you tell whats the problem? Thanks!

Comment: @Harshad can you share "create table" code. When I changed the fieldType to TEXT, it was solved.

Comment: I use TEXT as the datatype but still the '+' is ignored by the SQLITE. Have any other solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution:

String **Fieldtype** replaced with **Text**.

create table friend (rowid integer primary key autoincrement, 
        phone Text);

references

1. http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html
2. comments.

Answer (score 0):

try rawQuery:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO myTable(Col1, ColDate) VALUES(1,'+7777')";
db.rawQuery(sql ,null);
```